# Angular 7 test: changing material radio buttons options in Cypress.io

Tags: angular, angular7, cypress

I'm writing a Cypress.io test for a page that has Angular material radio buttons. I can read the selected option, and seemingly change the selected radio button, but my app does not recognize it as having been changed.

I've checked the documentation, but I don't see anything to help deal with this particular scenario. I've tried using .check() and .click() and they both result in the same issue.

I write that it seems to have worked because the right radio button is selected in the test runner UI. However, I know it hasn't triggered anything in Angular because the option hasn't been changed in the DB.

Here's the test. It correctly identifies which button is selected at the start, but does not actually change which button is selected.

```
it('Should change radio button', function() {
    cy.get('#mat-radio-3').should('have.attr', 'ng-reflect-checked', 'true');
    cy.get('[type="radio"]').first().check({force: true});
    cy.get('#mat-radio-2').should('have.attr', 'ng-reflect-checked', 'true');
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work with the Angular Material demo page https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples.

However, I could not find the attribute `ng-reflect-checked` so used class `mat-radio-checked` instead. If you watch the DOM when clicking the options, this class changes - at least on this example page.

This is the test I ran

```js
describe('clicking angular material radio', () => {

  it('Should change radio button', function() {
    cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples')

    cy.get('[type="radio"]').first().check({force: true});
    cy.get('#mat-radio-2').should('have.class', 'mat-radio-checked');
    cy.contains('.example-selected-value', 'Your favorite season is: Winter')

    cy.get('[type="radio"]').eq(1).check({force: true});
    cy.get('#mat-radio-3').should('have.class', 'mat-radio-checked');
    cy.contains('.example-selected-value', 'Your favorite season is: Spring')

    cy.get('[type="radio"]').eq(2).check({force: true});
    cy.get('#mat-radio-4').should('have.class', 'mat-radio-checked');
    cy.contains('.example-selected-value', 'Your favorite season is: Summer')

    cy.get('[type="radio"]').eq(3).check({force: true});
    cy.get('#mat-radio-5').should('have.class', 'mat-radio-checked');
    cy.contains('.example-selected-value', 'Your favorite season is: Autumn')

  })

})
```

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try that. Did the selection change? The class changes for me too, but the action is not triggered

Comment: Yes, there's a visual change in the view and the action gets actioned (ref `cy.contains` tests this).

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why mine isn’t working. Will try as soon as I get back to my machine.

Comment: I upgraded to Cypress 3.1.4 and tried your version and it worked. Thanks!